# StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 73

Tags: java, exception, stream

I have found lots of posts for other invalid type codes of this exception (AC, 00), but cannot find what code "73" means. What does 73 indicate in:

```
StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 73
```

Comment: @Naman why was this closed? I specifically mentioned that question. AC and 73 are not the same error code!

Comment: It means your code using `ObjectXXXStream` is wrong, the actual type code doesn't have much relevance in this case.